# Perl: How to check if any one value is <

Tags: arrays, perl, operators

I have an array like @array=(1,2,3,4)

I also have a scalar, lets say 2.  How do I check and see that there is one number less than 2, one number equal to 2, and 2 numbers greater than 2?

Comment: What have you tried this far mate?  You at least should try opening your programming book before jumping on the forums to get people to do your homework for you.  You're just going to need a `for` loop, so I'd look for that in the index first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each element and add to a counter, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw/ 1 2 3 4/;

my $lower = 0;
my $equal = 0;
my $higher = 0;

for my $i (@array)
{
    if ($i < 2) { $lower += 1; }
    elsif ($i == 2) { $equal += 1; }
    else { $higher += 1; }
}
print "There are $lower elements lower than 2\n";
print "There are $equal elements equal to 2\n";
print "There are $higher elements higher than 2\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed to know that $i was the magic solution, but thanks.

Comment: `$i` isn't the magic solution. It's a poor name for a variable that is usually used as an array index.